# NSNotification fails.... Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to get NSNotifications to work. At this moment, without success.

In my appDelegate.m file I have:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"first" object:nil];
```

In my mainViewController.m, in the viewDidLoad method I have

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(firstRun)name:@"first" object:nil];
```

and created a method (in mainViewController.m as well):

```
-(void) firstRun:(NSNotification *) notification
{
        NSLog(@"This works!");
}
```

However, I do not see any output in the log when running the app.

What is wrong with my code? Please advise.

Comment: Adri, when you have time, please click the checkmark next to one of the answers below, so that this question is marked as answered and is considered closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above, which points out that you had used the wrong selector in the observer method, is definitely a problem.

Another thing that you should check is that you add the observer before the notification is posted. Notifications are synchronous. When posted, they will only be recognized by observers that are already registered.

I recommend that you set a breakpoint on the line where you post the notification, and also on the line where you add the observer, and see which gets hit first.

Comment: I don't understand this, please explain. Where and how can I test it? Is it correct to say that my ViewDidLoad has to be called in mainViewController.m before the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions in teh appDelegate.m? Is that the normal behavior?

Comment: To test it, you can run the code in the Simulator, using Xcode.  If you access the .view property of your view controller or call [mainViewController view] in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: before you post the notification, that will cause your viewDidLoad method to get called on your view controller before you post your notification.

Comment: thank you for your replies. Setting two breakpoints learned me that the postNotification is "loaded" before the observer gets it. This will not gonna work (I think)

Answer (score 5):

Wrong selector, should be:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(firstRun:)name:@"first" object:nil];
```

Comment: Edit the question, it has to be firstRun. Was typo in my question. In my code it is correct. No change -> no output in NSLog.

Comment: @AdriOosterwijk You missed the key detail here. You need to add the colon (:) after firstRun like `firstRun:` because you have an argument your passing through the selector.

Comment: @ 0x7ffffff and Mark, I learned that the observer must be loaded before the post calls it.In my situation it is the other way around. I think I have to rework some thinks to get it all done. Thank you for your replies.